# Multisite - Get current post id

Tags: posts, multisite, switch-to-blog

I'm using WPMU in my project, but I'm facing some problems to get the current post id from all sites. If I run this code, I receive the same post id of current site and not the different post id from all other sites. It's like that `switch_to_blog` doesn't work. How can I get all ids of current post from all sites?

```
$sites = get_sites();

/** @var WP_Site $site */
foreach ($sites as $site) {
    if ( $site->archived || $site->spam || $site->deleted ) {
        continue;
    }

    switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );
    var_dump( get_the_ID() );
}
restore_current_blog();
die;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. you want the ID of the current post ? or you want all posts of a blog ?

Comment: @Kaperto I want the ID of current post of all sites

Comment: a post is associated to 1 site then it cannot be at "all sites".

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sites = get_sites();
global $switched;

/** @var WP_Site $site */
foreach ($sites as $site) {
if ( $site->archived || $site->spam || $site->deleted ) {
    continue;
}

switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );
$all_posts = get_posts('category=-3&numberposts=6&orderby=post_name&order=DSC');
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($all_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo 
         $post->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
    </li>                                
<?php endforeach ; ?>
</ul>
<?php
}
restore_current_blog();
die;
```

Comment: same problem, I receive the same post id e not the different post id for each site

Comment: ok then you need to loop all the post.

Comment: see the answer now

Comment: In this way I receive the first six posts of current site

Comment: this function is working fine in my current wp mu setup

Answer (score 0):

use `global $post`. And use `$post->ID`

Comment: It doesn't work, same problem